# CSS for window title after using setTitle in Extjs

Tags: css, extjs, window

I have a requirement where i need to show extjs window title as the below code snippet.And this is dynamic means i need to show this after using setTitle() for window.
Please share your ideas if any.

```css
body {
  background-color: #47d1da;}
p {
  color: white;
  font: 300 4em/150% Impact;
  text-align: center;}


/* loading dots */

.loading:after {
  content: ' .';
  animation: dots 1s steps(5, end) infinite;}

@keyframes dots {
  0%, 20% {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0),
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  40% {
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0),
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  60% {
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 white,
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  80%, 100% {
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 white,
      .5em 0 0 white;}}
```

```html
<p class="loading">Login in progress</p>
```

Comment: You mean that you need to show three dots in above fashion for window's title ? am I right ?

Comment: Yes Tejas...Exactly but it should be done after setting the title dynamically.Not while window is created.

Comment: After you call setTitle(), you can put some timer like setInterval() and then update these dots dynamically. Wont it solve problem ?

Comment: Can you share the code how you init/create the window. Do you know the setLoading method from extjs? I assume if you call setTitle that the window is created already, now you can swap the css classes as well by using add or removeCls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set cls as following

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.MyWin',{
extend:'Ext.window.Window',
title : 'Initial title',
xtype:'myWin',
width:200,
height:300,
initComponent:function(){
    this.callParent();
    this.setTitle({
        cls : 'testTitle',
        text : 'Changed'
    });
}})
```

Also you can find working example here https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/35ns

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who suggested their answers.
I could able to achieve this by using below lines of code.
window.header.setTitle();
window.header.getTitle().addCls()
those lines worked for me.